Cambiar color a boton con valores de obtenidos de tres combobox en Java. No responde los eventos
Haciendo un ejerció de un vídeo tutorial de youtube se me presento el problema de que ninguno de los botones me responden.
Al oprimir el botón button1 este debería cambiar de color según los valores escogidos en los 3 ComboBox y al oprimir el botón button2 se debería cerrar el programa pero no pasa nada. Al compilarlo no me arroja ningún error de sintaxis así que el error debe ser lógico pero no lo logro ver.
¿Alguien me le puede echar una mirada al código? Gracias y disculpen la molestia
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColorRGB extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    private JButton button1, button2;
    
    private JComboBox combo1,
                      combo2,
                      combo3;
                                        
    private JLabel label1,
                   label2,
                   label3;
    
    public ColorRGB(){
        setLayout(null);
        
        // Estructura de diseño de la etiqueta y combo Rojo 
        
        label1 = new JLabel("Rojo:");
        label1.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 10);
        add(label1);
        
        combo1 = new JComboBox();
        combo1.setBounds(120, 10, 50, 30);
        for(int i = 0; i <= 255; i++){
            combo1.addItem(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        add(combo1);
        
        // Estructura de diseño de la etiqueta y combo Rojo
        
        label2 = new JLabel("Verde:");
        label2.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 10);
        add(label2);
        
        combo2 = new JComboBox();
        combo2.setBounds(120, 50, 50, 30);
        for(int j = 0; j <= 255; j++){
            combo2.addItem(String.valueOf(j));
        }
        add(combo2);
        
        // Estructura de diseño de la etiqueta y combo Azul
        
        label3 = new JLabel("Azul:");
        label3.setBounds(10, 90, 100, 10);
        add(label3);
        
        combo3 = new JComboBox();
        combo3.setBounds(120, 90, 50, 30);
        for(int k = 0; k <= 255; k++){
            combo3.addItem(String.valueOf(k));
        }
        add(combo3);
        
        // Estructura de diseño del boton para cambiar de color
    
        button1 = new JButton("Fijar Color");
        button1.setBounds(10, 130, 110, 30);
        add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        
        // Estructura de diseño del boton para cerrar programa
    
        button2 = new JButton("Cerrar");
        button2.setBounds(130, 130, 110, 30);
        add(button2);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == combo1){
            String variable1 = combo1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String variable2= combo2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String variable3 = combo3.getSelectedItem().toString();
            
            int rojo = Integer.parseInt(variable1);
            int verde = Integer.parseInt(variable2);
            int azul = Integer.parseInt(variable3);
        
            Color color_valores = new Color(rojo, verde, azul);
            button1.setBackground(color_valores);
        }
        
        if(e.getSource() == combo2){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ColorRGB FA = new ColorRGB();
        FA.setBounds(0, 0, 260, 220);
        FA.setVisible(true);
        FA.setResizable(false);
        FA.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    
}

Veo y reviso por todos lados pero no logro ver el error. Algo hice mal en la linea donde programe los dos eventos en donde se cambia el color y donde se cirra el programa pero no se cual es el error.

¿Qué valor tiene e.getSource()? ¿Depuraste tu código?

e.getSource() == button1...e.getSource() == button2

es que estas tratando de manejar los eventos de los jcombobox en lugar de los eventos de los botones.. la logica para cambiar el color del boton esta asociada al evento de los jcombobox en lugar de estar asociada al evento del boton.. tambien estas usando los jcombobox en los if dentro del metodo actionperformed pero no es ahi donde deberias verificar los evento si no en los botones 1 y 2, intenta con eso y nos dices como te fue..
a ver dale. asi...
 import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    
    public class ColorRGB extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
        
        private JButton button1, button2;
        private JComboBox combo1, combo2, combo3;
        private JLabel label1, label2, label3;
        
        public ColorRGB(){
            setLayout(null);
            
            // Estructura de diseño de la etiqueta y combo Rojo 
            label1 = new JLabel("Rojo:");
            label1.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 10);
            add(label1);
            
            combo1 = new JComboBox();
            combo1.setBounds(120, 10, 50, 30);
            for(int i = 0; i <= 255; i++){
                combo1.addItem(String.valueOf(i));
            }
            add(combo1);
            
            // Estructura de diseño de la etiqueta y combo Verde
            label2 = new JLabel("Verde:");
            label2.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 10);
            add(label2);
            
            combo2 = new JComboBox();
            combo2.setBounds(120, 50, 50, 30);
            for(int j = 0; j <= 255; j++){
                combo2.addItem(String.valueOf(j));
            }
            add(combo2);
            
            // Estructura de diseño de la etiqueta y combo Azul
            label3 = new JLabel("Azul:");
            label3.setBounds(10, 90, 100, 10);
            add(label3);
            
            combo3 = new JComboBox();
            combo3.setBounds(120, 90, 50, 30);
            for(int k = 0; k <= 255; k++){
                combo3.addItem(String.valueOf(k));
            }
            add(combo3);
            
            // Estructura de diseño del boton para cambiar de color
            button1 = new JButton("Fijar Color");
            button1.setBounds(10, 130, 110, 30);
            add(button1);
            button1.addActionListener(this);
            
            // Estructura de diseño del boton para cerrar programa
            button2 = new JButton("Cerrar");
            button2.setBounds(130, 130, 110, 30);
            add(button2);
            button2.addActionListener(this);
        }
        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource() == button1){
                String variable1 = combo1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String variable2= combo2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String variable3 = combo3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                
                int rojo = Integer.parseInt(variable1);
                int verde = Integer.parseInt(variable2);
                int azul = Integer.parseInt(variable3);
            
                Color color_valores = new Color(rojo, verde, azul);
                button1.setBackground(color_valores);
            }
            
            if(e.getSource() == button2){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        
        public static void main(String args[]){
            ColorRGB FA = new ColorRGB();
            FA.setBounds(0, 0, 260, 220);
            FA.setVisible(true);
            FA.setResizable(false);
            FA.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
    }


El error estaba en  los if como mencionaste. En ves de verificar button1 y button2 estaba verificando con los if a combo1 y combo2. Gracias.

ok, que bueno que lo lograste.. entonces paso a borrar mi codigo jejeje..

No lo borres. Tal vez alguien haga la misma pregunta alguna vez y le salta esta pregunta con tu respuesta codificada en Google y lo ayudes. Yo no hubiera conseguido la respuesta si no fuera por ti.
